# $_POST checking empty

Tags: php, arrays, post

I need a function which can check my `$_POST` array, for example see this code, there is nothing common in the `$_POST` array. But i want to check if the array is returning null value from the user.

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['action']) {
  case "one":
  $a=$_POST['a'];
  echo "your value is". $a;
  break;

  case "two":
  $b=$_POST['b'];
  $c=$_POST['c'];
  echo "your value is". $b."--".$c;
  break;

  case "three":
  $x=$_POST['x'];
  $y=$_POST['y'];
  $z=$_POST['z'];
  echo "your value is". $x."--".$y."--".$z;
  break;   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check like this:

```
$x = (isset($_POST['x']) && $_POST['x'] != "") ? $_POST['x'] : "" ;
echo "your value is". $x.";
```

As per your comment my updates:

```
function check_empty($item, $key)
{
    $item[$key] = (isset($item) && $item != "") ? $item : "" ;
}
array_walk($_POST, 'check_empty');
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh, But i need a common function to check my $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the $_POST array is empty using

```
empty($_POST)
```

And if you want to check for individual value is null,

```
empty($_POST['x'])
```

Something like:

```
$x = !empty($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : '';
```

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. But my ajax url is similar like

Comment: $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://www.exam.com/mob/dB_master_file.php?action=one",
          data: { one:1 }
          }).done(function( msg ) {
                                  page3(msg);
          }); In this case the empty($_POST) won't work because the $_POST array is not empty at all, it has a value $_POST['action']=one

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `isset()`

```
$a = null;
if ( isset($_POST['a']) ) {
   $a = $_POST['a'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I need a common function to check all the $_POST. and in the above case i don't have a common variable at all..!!